# Magento 2 New Account Confirmation Email Text Broken

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

after creating new account trying to login but get this kind of error message

`This account is not confirmed. <a href="http://example.com/customer/account/confirmation/?email=testuser%40mail.com">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.`

How can i fix this issue to get clickable link instead of html content?

Magento version is 2.3.5.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Please share your Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I override `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js` file with this one `app/design/frontend/<VENDOR_NAME>/<THEME_NAME>/Magento_Theme/web/js/view/messages.js` and then changed `prepareMessageForHtml` function like this

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },
        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
    initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });
            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {string}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let doc = parser.parseFromString(message, 'text/html');
            let html = doc.body.textContent;
            if (!html.includes("</a>")) {
                return message;
            }
            return html;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be a bug in Magento 2.3.5. It seems to be fixed in Magento 2.4.0 and upwards:

[image]

Please upgrade to Magento 2.4. If this issue still happens, it might be an issue in your third-party theme.

edit:

It got fixed in this PR: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/27662

The changes include switching from method `addErrorMessage` to `addComplexErrorMessage`, which can include templates in the message.

Answer (score 0):

Patch is available on Magento site;

Resend account confirmation email link issue patch for Magento 2.3.5

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download